# Cassandra:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, cassandra

I had no problem with `cassandra` but today I tried to install the latest cassandra ver ,after installing `cassandra` when i tried to run this command:

```
sudo cassandra -f
```

it result in this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/cassandra/service/CassandraDaemon : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon. Program        will exit.
```

---

```
java version "1.6.0_27" 
os:ubuntu 12.04 lts
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Comment: You need Java 7 to run applications with classes having version 51.0.

Comment: thanks,i can't change my java ver becaouse i'm writing a plugin for atlassian-jira and it works with java 6 ,now i'm tring to install cassandra 1.2.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the trunk version of cassandra uses jdk1.7, previous versions use jdk1.6. If you must use jdk1.6 stick with the cassandra-2.0 line (or earlier)

Comment: Is there no way to run Cassandra 2.0.6 in java 6